# How do I change the background colour of the table row using the fade out effect?

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to change the background color of the row (to red) when removing the row from the table.

This is my code so far:

```
$('.delete').click(function(){
    $id=$(this).attr('id');
    $row = $(this).parents('tr:first');
    $.ajax({
        url:'admin/delete_post',
        dataType:'json',
        type:'POST',
        data:'id=' + $id,
        error:function(){
            alert('There was an error');
        },
        success:function(data){
            $row.fadeOut(600,function(){
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }

    })
});
```

**EDIT: Included markup.**

```
<tr>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>
       <div class="controls ">
         <textarea class="input-xlarge span10" name="content" id="textarea" rows="5"                       
         cols="45">text</textarea>
       </div></td>
    <td>
      <a class="btn delete" id="58"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete</a>
      <a class="btn save" ><i class="icon-ok"></i> Save</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What does `$this` variable stand for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
success:function(data){
     $row.find('td').css('backgroundColor', 'red').end().fadeOut(600,function(){
          ...
     });
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. I've included the html just in case this changes the answers.

Comment: That worked. Can you explain why the other code didn't? Thanks.

Comment: For a while I forgot that applying a background color on a `tr` element has no effect on several browser

Answer (score 0):

In you post there is no sing of `$this`, I think it should `this`.

```
$row.css('background', 'red')
    .fadeOut(600,function(){
          $(this).remove();
    });
```